# Netdata display for multiple servers, like the one displayed on their cloud. Can I do this without the cloud?

Tags: netdata

I'm looking to use Netdata to monitor multiple nodes.   I realize I can have one node gather data from multiple nodes, and to use a customized dashboard display.  And I found that netdata cloud itself has a nice uncluttered display of multiple on a single page.  See the link to the image below. Can I create the same display on a local netdata installation, without using the cloud?  Thanks. - Mark

[Netdata single display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nar28.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort-of create a dashboard like that, using the custom dashboard functionality. In essence, you will create an `html` file that has charts from different nodes.

Since you are creating the HTML, you could layer it in a way that is analogous to the screenshot.

You can read more about custom dashboard on our [documentation](https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/web/gui/custom)

That being said, I think Netdata Cloud is the best solution there. Mind that we don't store any data. When you access the dashboard, the data is streamed directly from the node to your browser via the Netdata Cloud-Agent link.